# Embedding of a global field to local field of characteristic $p$/

Tags: number-theory, polynomials

Let $F=\mathbb{F}_q(t)$ and consider its completion $F_P$ with respect to an irreducible polynomial $P(t)$, namely the local field associated to the place $P$ (I understand this could be technically incorrect terminology but hopefully you see what I mean). Then one knows that $F_P$ is isomorphic to $F[t]/P ((P))$.

Just to confirm, the map $F\hookrightarrow F_P$ is not very easy to describe explicitly right? By that I mean if we know $P=t^n+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_it^i$ you will have to go through some tedious calculation to obtain where $t$ maps to (in terms of the 'usual' expansion of $F_P$.

Motivation for this question is [Property of Derivative in a local field](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1533814/property-of-derivative-in-a-local-field).